# Same content on different slugs

Tags: slug, channels, entry-slug

I hope someone can help me to understand this.

I have a Channel called eg. "My channel". In that channel i have two entries:
 Post 1 and Post 2. Those two entries have different titles and content.

If I go to "my-channel/post-1" in the browser, and then to "my-channel/post-2" they have the same content based on the Post 2 (last created entry).

If I make "Post 2" inactive, then Post 1 will have the correct content.

What am i forgetting here?

Comment: How is your section Entry URI Format and Template setup?

Comment: My entry URI is: my-channel/{slug} , and in the folder templates I have the folder my-channel with a _entry.twig file in it.

It is like it takes the latest created entry and then all the slugs goes to that content.

Comment: Is your _entry.twig file setting the entry manually or are you retrieving all of the channel at some point in the template?

Comment: Do you mean like the for loop: {% for entry in craft.entries.section('my-channel').limit(1).all() %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your Entry URI is setup as my-channel/{slug} , When you go to my-channel/post-slug-1 Craft automatically sets the variable 'entry' to the entry post-slug-1. You don't need to loop through the channel at this point. You can just use the entry variable.

```
entry.fieldName
entry.slug
entry.url
```

etc...

So just remove your for loop and use 'entry'

Using

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('my-channel').limit(1).all() %}
```

Will get the first entry of the my-channel section. That's useful for pages where you need to list out all of your entries in that section or get specific ones.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the explanation. It worked out Great :)